# View Method Specifying Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, partial-views

Does anyone know the proper syntax on how to specify the model that you are attempting to use for a specific view?  In my application, I used the MVCScaffolding NuGet Package and when you scaffold something, it creates the CRUD views for you.  Problem I'm having is that I wanted to have a partial view loaded on a parent's view and cannot for the life of me get the syntax correct.

The MSDN reference for what I'm attempting to do is here:

[View Method (String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310.aspx)

I have a Category model and an Item model and I want to add Items to a category in the Category detail view.  So, I was wanting to load the partial view _CreateOrEdit for the Item model in a dialog but cannot figure out the syntax for specifying a model.

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your desire is to render a partial view, the method to use is [RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial.aspx).

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_CreateOrEdit", Model);}
```

EDIT:

Re-reading your question, is your question how to specify a specific model for your view returned within a controller? If so it would simply be something like this:

```
Return View("ViewName", model);
```

Comment: Yes but that doesn't quite answer my question, I don't know how to specify the model.  The syntax above is simply what is in the MSDN documentation.  I am attempting to specify a different model than the view that I'm currently using...this make sense?